# Probability of machine being adjusted unnecessarily

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In my math book I found the following problem:

> Some company bottles a liquid in bottles of X ml, where X is
>   distributed normally.
>   $\mu_X = 400$ and $\sigma_X = 4$.

(I'm not sure of the adjective form of [normal distribution](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution)).

> Assume $\mu_X$ slowly drifts off. To prevent this, the company takes
>   samples of 25 bottles (with normally distributed average $\overline{X}$
>   ) adjusts the machine if $\overline{X} \leq 399 \vee \overline{X} \geq 401$.
>   a) Calculate the probability the company adjusts the machine
>   unjustly.
>   b) Why is it not possible to calculate the probability the
>   company adjusts the machine justly?
>   — Translated and paraphrased by yours truly.

To me, it seems the probabilities discussed in a) and b) are complementary, so b) would be wrong; it is possible to calculate "the probability the company adjusts the machine justly": $P(b) = 1 - P(a)$.

In the past, there have been some minor mistakes in this series, but they were rather small (typos, omissions), so I think my reasoning is flawed. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjusting unjustly comes to: $\mu_X=400$ and $\overline{X}\notin(399,401)$. Fully informed about the distribution we can find the probability of event $\overline{X}\notin(399,401)$.

Adjusting justly comes to: $\mu_X\neq400$ and $\overline{X}\notin(399,401)$. However the information $\mu_X\neq400$ is not telling us the real value of $\mu_X$ so in this situation we *cannot* find the probability of event $\overline{X}\notin(399,401)$.

There is a third possibility: no adjusting takes place. That illustrates that the two possibilities mentioned above are not complementary.

---

**Edit**:

I withdraw my remark about 'not complementary'. It is 'too easy' and not consistent with the rest of my answer. For a discussion on that see the comments on this answer.

Comment: "There is a third possibility: no adjusting takes place. That illustrates that the two possibilities mentioned above are not complementary."  It's not that the probabilities in a) and b) don't add to $1$; it's that their sum isn't even meaningful.  You cannot add two conditional probabilities where you are conditioning on different events.  Consider $$\Pr[\text{I fail to win the lottery}\mid\text{it's Tuesday}]+\Pr[\text{I fail to win the lottery}\mid\text{it isn't Tuesday}].$$  Both terms are nearly equal to $1$, so their sum is nearly equal to $2$.  The sum isn't a probability at all.

Comment: @WillOrrick Thank you. I am not ready with your comment yet, and unfortunately I must go. I will come back later. Is anything wrong with $P\left(\text{machine is adjusted justly}\right)+P\left(\text{machine is adjusted unjustly}\right)=P\left(\text{machine is adjusted}\right)$? Cheers.

Comment: In response to your comment to my own answer, I'm having to rethink the conditional probability formulation of my objection.  Yet I still feel that the essence of my objection is correct: it isn't sensible to add probabilities defined with respect to different probability measures.  Using hypothesis testing language, Pr[machine is adjusted justly] is defined subject to the hypothesis $\mu_X=400$.  It wouldn’t make sense to add this to the probability Pr[machine is adjusted unjustly] defined, say, subject to the hypothesis $\mu_X=390$.  Even more problematic...

Comment: ... is Pr[machine is adjusted unjustly] defined subject to $\mu_X\ne400$ since the latter is a composite hypothesis and therefore doesn’t define a single probability measure.  Similarly, the right side of the equation, Pr[machine is adjusted], is not really defined since it is subject to the composite hypothesis $\mu_X=\ $anything.

Comment: While it may be illegitimate to apply conditional probability to this problem, a similar phenomenon occurs there.  Conditioning on an event $B$ defines a probability measure, and it doesn’t make sense to add probabilities conditioned on different events.  In particular, $\Pr[A\mid B]+\Pr[A\mid B’]$ isn’t a sensible probability.  What you can, of course, do is to use Bayes’ theorem and write $\Pr[A\mid B]\Pr[B]+\Pr[A\mid B’]\Pr[B’]=\Pr[A]$.

Comment: In the example at hand, I guess I was imagining that the company periodically runs the test.  In between tests, the value of $\mu_X$ drifts randomly, and so itself might be described by a probability distribution.  This is not my area of expertise, so perhaps this is not a legitimate viewpoint, but I was thinking it might be possible to formulate a Bayes-theorem-like analysis that makes sense of phrases such as "probability the company adjusts the machine justly/unjustly".

Comment: @WillOrrick Your critics on my answer concerning complementation is correct. My
answer is (in your terms) based upon $1=P\left(A\cap B'\right)+P\left(A\cap B\right)+P\left(A'\right)$
so is inconsistent with the way $P\left(\text{adjustly unjustly}\right)$
was calculated in my answer as: $P\left(A\mid B\right)$.